# How to use v-model and computed properties on Input fields?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple component with 2 input fields:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
        <input type="text" v-model="alias">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: "",
                alias: ""
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to automatically insert the `name` model's value to the `alias` field IF the `alias` field is empty. If it's not empty, I want it to use its own value.

Here is my attempt:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
        <input type="text" v-model="alias">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: "",
                alias: ""
            }
        },
        computed: {
            alias: {
                get: function() {
                    if (this.alias.length < 1) {
                        return this.name
                    } else {
                        return this.alias
                    }
                },
                set: function(newValue) {
                    this.alias = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that `alias` doesn't get the actual value in the `alias` property if I type something into the `name` field. I can only see it visually - but it doesn't hold the value. However, if I type into the `alias` field, it gets updated properly.

What am I missing here and how can I make it the way I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed won't work because it should be treated as immutable.

Also because the model will be updated on each input, a watch won't work either, it would only pick up the first char of what you enter, unless its pre-populated.

This is how I would do it, simply add a `@blur` event on the name input then fire a method which populates alias if it's empty and on alias in case they empty it out.

The same method could be used in mounted, if you pre-populate the models, or you could watch it.

```
{
  template: `
  <div>
     <input type="text" v-model="name" @blur="setAlias()">
      <input type="text" v-model="alias" @blur="setAlias()">
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      alias: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAlias() {
      if (this.alias === '') {
        this.alias = this.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot have a computed property and a data property with the same name. Since both computed and data properties end up as properties on the same state object, one will overwrite the other.

Secondly, and I think you did this because of the first point, in your computed `alias` getter, your reference the `alias` again, which is essentially referencing itself, and looks like it could give some inconsistent return values.

I can think of two solutions to your issue:

**1) Use a watcher on `name`:**

Create a watcher function for `name`, and in it set `this.alias` to the same value as `name` when `alias` is blank, or if it's the same as the previous name value.

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            name: "",
            alias: ""
        }),
        watch: {
            name(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (!this.alias || this.alias === oldVal) {
                    this.alias = newVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**2) Use explicit `:value` and `@change`/`@keyup` bindings on the name input:**

`v-model` is a convenience method that sets both of these for you, but in your case you want to do some more logic in the change handler that just setting a state property value.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          :value="name"
          @keyup="onNameInput"
        />
        <input type="text" v-model="alias">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            name: "",
            alias: ""
        }),
        methods: {
            // Check and set both values on name input events
            onNameInput(e) {
                if (!this.alias || this.alias === this.name) {
                    this.alias = e.target.value;
                }
                this.name = e.target.value;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted, both your examples are not what the op asked for, the first one appends if the same [see](https://playcode.io/565714), the second one doesn't work at all [see](https://playcode.io/565717), whilst my answer works perfectly [see](https://playcode.io/565722)

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone , I fixed the typo in the second option I gave